# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named '_ctypes' Mac M1

Tags: python, macos

While installing some libraries you may find the issue `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named '_ctypes'`

Answer (score 25):

**Short version:**

Try installing python 3.7.13 with [pyenv](https://github.com/pyenv/pyenv):
`pyenv install 3.7.13`, and if that does not work, try python 3.7.12 (`pyenv install 3.7.12`).

The [pyenv release 2.2.3](https://github.com/pyenv/pyenv/releases/tag/v2.2.3) addresses the compilation problems for 3.6.15/3.7.12 on M1 macs, specifically for [ctypes](https://github.com/pyenv/pyenv/pull/2190).

**Long version:**

The underlying cause for the `_ctypes` error seems to be that libffi cannot be found during the compilation, and is therefore (silently) skipped during the Python installation.

There is a comprehensive overview for installing different versions using pyenv [at this page](https://laict.medium.com/install-python-on-macos-11-m1-apple-silicon-using-pyenv-12e0729427a9), some specific versions require homebrew patches. [Here is an overview of those patches](https://github.com/Homebrew/formula-patches/tree/master/python). However, I would try installing them without the patches first, as the pyenv team has fixed various compilation problems since that post was written.

The general syntax for installing with a patch is:
`pyenv install --patch X.X.X <<(curl -sSL link_to_patch)` where `X.X.X` is the version you want to install.

Another solution is to [use an x86 version of homebrew](https://github.com/pyenv/pyenv/issues/1768#issuecomment-871602950).

Officially, [Python 3.7 and lower are not supported on Apple Silicon](https://bugs.python.org/msg382939).

Comment: Thanks, this worked for me on my M1; updated pyenv to 2.3.0, then removed and reinstalled my python-3.7.13 and pyenv virtualenv, and now it can find ctypes. 
(My codebase isn't ready for 3.8 or later)

Answer (score 13):

Make sure you are running python 3.8.10 +

Comment: You saved my day!

Comment: But can't core m1 use python version less than 3.7

Comment: Mac has its default version of python installed, which is 2.7.x. I've additionally installed python3, its version being 3.9.9 and I still get the error. Any hint on how to solve it, or if when installing a package then it goes for the Mac's default python version?

Comment: Any solution for python 3.7 ?

Comment: @Arti Did you figure out a solution for 3.7?

Comment: @UpTheCreek no, unfortunately. Moved to 3.10 to own risk

Answer (score 1):

Updating to Python 3.7.13 (or higher versions) should solve the problem.